# React Native Mapbox gl Initial Center Coordinates

Tags: ios, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl, react-native-mapbox-gl

So I am trying to set my initial center coordinates for mapbox so they are not 0,0.  On the api it says mapbox expects a prop of

```
initialCenterCoordinate object  Optional    Initial latitude/longitude the map will load at.    { latitude:0, longitude: 0 }
```

So I am doing

```
<Mapbox
    initialCenterCoordinate={latitude: 40.444328, longitude: -79.953155} .... other props/>
```

This is giving me an error on that line saying unexpected token, expecting }.

Whenever I do something like

```
<Mapbox
    initialCenterCoordinate={{latitude: 40.444328, longitude: -79.953155}} .... other props/>
```

It still sets my initial spot to 0,0. Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:
link to git hub page- https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl

Comment: initialCenterCoordinate is not working, any other solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
<MapboxGL.MapView
  key='mainmap'
  style={{ flex: 1 }}>

   <MapboxGL.Camera
     zoomLevel={2}
     centerCoordinate={[2.21, 46.22]}/>

<MapboxGL.MapView />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor try with:

```
this.state = {
     position : {
        latitude: 49.437090,
        longitude: 1.097456,
     }
};
```

And:

```
<MapView initialCenterCoordinate={this.state.position}> </MapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/MapView.md) the value should be an array

```
 <Mapbox
     initialCenterCoordinate={[40.444328, -79.953155]} .... other props/>
```